# Check to see a website has one of multiple words - if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, python-requests

I want to check to see if a website have at least 1 of multiple words. I can only find one word. When I try to add multiple words, I get error.

```
 import requests

 url = 'https://www.python.org/'

 r = requests.get(url)
 html_content = r.text
 list = "Calculations" # This works
 # list = ("Calculations", "simple") # this would fail

 if list in html_content:
     print("word exist")
```

thanks to everybody that helps.

Comment: Can you please show the error?

Comment: Try using [] to indicate a list. These brackets () produce a *tuple* and I'm not sure the `in` operator works with those.

Comment: `list` is a builtin function, it might pay to use another variable name e.g. `words`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight forward way to modify your code would be:

```
words = ("Calculations", "simple")

for word in words:
    if word in html_content:
        print("word exists")
```

This searches the whole text over and over, better to tokenize and use intersection of sets as mentioned by @CaptainMeow in his answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! that is exactly what I need to know. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to get around the issue:

First, you can simply loop through the list of words and check one by one. But let's go with something far more complicated eh?

With the text you get from your html. Remove punctuations, remove white space, lowercase everything and all that jazz, then convert the list of words into a set. Let's call this `vocab_set`. By luck you also have your own `word_set`, which is a set containing the words whose existence you want to verify in the html text. All you need to do at that point is type `vocab_set & word_set`, which gives you the intersection of two sets, or the words that exist in the webpage.

Yes, I just went through all that trouble for the one liner at the end.